# jquery attributes from multiple elements

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I am trying ot figure how to use jQuery to get the value of html attribute of many elements. My webpage updates dynamically using ajax. I have an attribute called number for in element in the part that is updated. I want to use the attribute value from each element so that i can use that data as parameters to a php file link. I have come across jquery's .attr() function, but it only seems to take the attribute value of the first element if finds. But what I want to do is get the attribute value for each element so that when I click on that element its corresponding attribute value is sent as parameters to the php file.

Thanks

Answer (score 11):

you can combine attr() with [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) method.

e.g.

```
$("div").each(function(){
     $(this).attr("number");
});
```

Answer (score 8):

**Disclaimer:** *This most likely does not respond to the OP question (after re-reading), but will stay for some time in case it fill some need of the OP*.

---

Use the [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) method

```
var numbers = $('[number]').map(function(){
  return $(this).attr('number');
});
```

this will create an array filled with the `number` attribute of all the elements that have one.

Comment: Not sure how this applies, better re-read the question ;) "when I click on that element its corresponding attribute value is sent as parameters to the php file"

Comment: .. @Nick you must be correct.. got confused by the rest of the question and the first answer.. I will leave it for a bit in case it offers any added benefit to the OP, and delete it later on.

Answer (score 3):

Inside a `click` handler (or any event handler), `this` will refer to that element, for example:

```
$("#content").delegate("a", "click", function() {
  alert($(this).attr("something")); //alerts "something" for the <a> you clicked
});
```

In this case we're using [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) because you said "My webpage updates dynamically using ajax", so just attach the handler to a parent element that's *not* replaced via AJAX and it'll work for all elements you add beneath...in the example above we're binding to all `<a>` elements, but just change the [selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) accordingly.

Comment: This is actually much closer to the needs of the OP. +1!